# How to deal with global, mutable configuration variables (or files) in FP?

Tags: functional-programming, global-variables

In a complex program, in which I am trying to apply functional programming patterns whenever I can, one problem is that many config files are just loaded and become a global variables accessible from everywhere in the program. This approach leads to entanglement. How should I handle config files in a functional programming style?

Comment: As long as your global variables are constants, I see no harm or un-functional (impure) programming style?

Comment: The list of last executed commands for example is not a constant, it gets updated. In this sense, maybe "config file" is not a correct name.

Comment: That sounds like a log file? Or do you actually read from that file/list in your application?

Comment: Yes, it is read and written immediately when something changes. I have "configs" like list of open files, visited directories, selected theme colors. They are read on startup, and sometimes re-read by various parts of the program, i.e. when a new editor window opens, it will also check to add itself to a list of opened/visited files. I realize that I approach this problem in exactly the same style as back in 199x years, which is frustrating. In fact this part is the most obscure and entangled of the whole project.

Comment: Model the config as a function and not as global variable.

Answer (score 2):

Modelling the configuration variables as a function seems reasonable to me. What it inferes is that the function will be impure and dependant on the state, namely the config file.